# What does 'de' mean at the beginning of this sentence?

Tags: de, que

> "D'hostile qu'elle était et disposée à le pendre, il avait peu à peu
> amené sa femme à l'adorer comme un dieu" (Jouhandeau, *Cocu, Pendu et
> Content*, 1951).

Does the opening *de* means 'as' (like *aussi*) or is it something different?

Comment: De  (hostile) .... à (l'adorer) → from ... to (not saying I'd put it that way in English though, most probably not)

Answer (score 8):

From *original order of things* to *new order of things*.

> From the hostile person she had been, bound to have him hanged, he had gradually brought his wife around to worship him as a god.

It's a little surprising grammatically that *hostile et disposée*, a pair of adjectives, are contrasted with *adorer*, a verb. I've tried to reflect that slight discrepancy in the English as well. But I suppose it doesn't impede the understanding at all.

Answer (score 4):

*De* is here the preposition that indicates the starting point of something to be matched to *à* that indicates the point of arrival (aller/amener de A à B).

- Il avait peu à peu amené sa femme **d**'une attitude hostile **à** l'adoration.

Answer (score 0):

The prepodition « de », so used, is meant to introduce a contrast between a situation and a subsequent one that  is considered as an evolution of the former, which one can't be extant any more, unless the evolution is reckoned with as hypothetical.

> (TLFi) **I.−** De prend une valeur sémantique en corrélation avec celle du mot subséquent.
> **A.−** De exprime le point de départ.
> **5.** Le point de départ est une situation antérieurement donnée.
> **a)** Le point de départ est une situation concrète.
> ♦ Réveiller qqn du milieu du sommeil; sortir d' une séance de travail.
> ♦ De ce mariage étaient issus de vrais géants (Loti, Mariage,1882, p. 28).
> **− En partic. Point de départ d'une évolution, d'une transformation (passage d'un état à un autre, d'une qualité à une autre)**.
> ♦ De commis, il devint directeur; de pauvre il devint riche (Littré). [user LPH : voir note ci-dessus]
> ♦ De vingt pièces de quatre ans, il m'en reste dix-huit (Hamp, Champagne,1909, p. 120).
> ♦ Les hommes s'activaient pour faire vin blanc du raisin noir par pressurage du fruit très frais (Hamp, Champagne,1909p. 141)
> ♦ Le mythe de la « création » nous séduit à vouloir faire quelque chose de rien. Je rêve donc que je trouve progressivement mon ouvrage à partir de pures conditions de forme, de plus en plus réfléchies... Valéry, Variété III,1936, p. 65.
> ♦ On devait faire de nous des apôtres, des gens dont le royaume n'est pas de ce monde. Et nous y tenions, à ce monde, nous y tenions par des fibres secrètes. Bernanos, Monsieur Ouine,1943, p. 1507.
> Rem. Cf. aussi les loc. fig. faire d'une pierre deux coups, faire de nécessité vertu, etc.

I believe that an ideal translation is given by Google Translate.

- Hostile as she was and willing to hang him, he had gradually led his wife to worship him like a god.

*Examples*

- De simple curiosité lorsqu'on avait commencé à en parler l'opinion publique en avait fait un mythe.
- D'innocent et farouche il avait évolué pour devenir un être plus sensé, plus réceptif à des explications raisonnées.
- D'insignifiante qu'elle était en tant que ville de province il aurait voulu qu'en quelques années elle soit devenue un centre économique régional.

<sub>**Note**: In my opinion, the activity of "commis" is not a concrete situation, nor is the state of being "pauvre" (financially poor) or "hostile (french)"; nevertheless the usages fits into that category (**a)**), and very precisely into the "**en partic.**" subcategory.</sub>